# Can't store and then read Files in PostgreSQL as large objects

Tags: c#, .net, database, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to write and read large objects to a PostgreSQL database V9.4.x using NpgSQL v3.0.4.0. So, I implemented a method to store a local file in the database as a large object like below:

```cs
public static async Task<uint> InsertLargeObjectFileToDB(string theFilePath)
{
         // connecting to DB
         string connstring = MakeDatabaseConnectionString();
         // make a connection object
         NpgsqlConnection Conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
         try
         {
            await OpenDatabaseConnection(Conn); //open database connection
         }
         catch (Exception Ex)
         {
            throw (Ex);
         }

         uint oid; // to store object ID number
         try
         {
            // Reading and writing Large Objects requires the use of a transaction

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(theFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
               using (var transaction = Conn.BeginTransaction())
               {
                  // Retrieve a Large Object Manager for this connection
                  var manager = new NpgsqlLargeObjectManager(Conn);
                  // Create a new empty file, returning the identifier to later access it
                  oid = manager.Create();

                  using (var DbStream = manager.OpenReadWrite(oid))
                  {
                     long theFileSize = GetFileSizeInBytes(theFilePath);
                     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
                     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];

                     while (sr.BaseStream.Position < theFileSize)
                     {
                        await fs.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        await DbStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                     }
                  }
                  transaction.Commit();
                  return oid;
               }
            }
         }
         catch // any error
         {
            // exception
            Exception ex = new Exception();
            ex.Data.Add(ex.Data.Count, "some error message");
            throw ex;
         }
    }
```

Then I implemented another method to read a large object and store it in a randomly named file in the temp directory, like this:

```cs
public static async Task<string> GetLargeObjectFileFromDB(uint oid)
{
         // connecting to DB
         string connstring = MakeDatabaseConnectionString();
         // make a connection object
         NpgsqlConnection Conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
         try
         {
            await OpenDatabaseConnection(Conn); //open database connection
         }
         catch (Exception Ex)
         {
            throw (Ex);
         }

         // getting a temorary file name from the system to use it to store the fetched file
         string TempFileName = GetRandomFileNameFromSystem();

         try
         {
            using (FileStream LocalStream = new FileStream(TempFileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
               using (var transaction = Conn.BeginTransaction())
               {
                  // create a Large Object Manager for this connection
                  var DbLargeObjectManager = new NpgsqlLargeObjectManager(Conn);

                  using (var DbStream = await DbLargeObjectManager.OpenReadAsync(oid))
                  {
                     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                     // get the length of the database object
                     long LengthOfDbObject = DbStream.Length;

                     while (DbStream.Position < LengthOfDbObject)
                     {
                        // read from the database to buffer
                        await DbStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        //write from buffer to local file
                        await LocalStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                     }
                  }
                  transaction.Commit();
                  return TempFileName;
               }
            }
         }
         catch // any error
         {
            // exception
            Exception ex = new Exception();
            ex.Data.Add(ex.Data.Count, "Error inserting object in database");
            throw ex;
         }
}
```

As you can see, I am writing asynchronously all the way. The problem is that I made a test for these 2 methods and this test write 6MB file to the database, but when I read that file again from the database it is about 400 kb larger and (of course) MD5 hashes do not match. Not to forget mentioning that no exception happen whatsoever. Here is the test if you're interested:

```cs
private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         listBox1.Items.Clear();

         // getting the MD5 hash of the source file
         string FirstMd5Hash = GetMd5OfFile(tbSourceFile.Text);

         // performance measurment ##########################################
         DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
         listBox1.Items.Add("Uploading file to database");
         //storing that file into database
         uint oid = await InsertLargeObjectFileToDB(tbSourceFile.Text);

         // performance measurment #########################################################
         DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
         TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(dt2.Ticks - dt1.Ticks);
         listBox1.Items.Add("Large object (oid = " + oid + ") inserted in " + ts.Seconds + "." + ts.Milliseconds + " seconds");

         // performance measurment ##########################################
         dt1 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
         listBox1.Items.Add("reading file back from the database");
         // get that object back from the database into temporary file
         string ReturnedFileName = await PostgresqlLargeObject.GetLargeObjectFileFromDB(oid);
         // performance measurment #########################################################
         dt2 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
         ts = new TimeSpan(dt2.Ticks - dt1.Ticks);
         listBox1.Items.Add("reading done in " + ts.Seconds + "." + ts.Milliseconds + " seconds");


         //calculate md5 of that file
         string SecondMd5Hash = GetMd5OfFile(ReturnedFileName);

         // compare the 2 hashes
         if (FirstMd5Hash == SecondMd5Hash)
         {
            listBox1.Items.Add("the hashes are match . MD5 = " + FirstMd5Hash);
         }
         else
         {
            listBox1.Items.Add("failed with oid = " + oid);
            tbFileBack.Text = ReturnedFileName;
         }
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the problem. Taking [Emil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556495/emil)'s answer into account, it turned out that you have to read asynchronously then write synchronously. I have no idea why is that, but this code works:

```cs
using (FileStream LocalStream = new FileStream(TempFileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var transaction = Conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // create a Large Object Manager for this connection
        var DbLargeObjectManager = new NpgsqlLargeObjectManager(Conn);
    
        using (var DbStream = await DbLargeObjectManager.OpenReadAsync(oid))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[262144]; //256KB
            // query the database stream length

            long DatabaseStreamLength = DbStream.Length;
            while (DbStream.Position < DatabaseStreamLength)
            {
                // read from the database to buffer (async)
                int bufferByteCount = await DbStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                //write from buffer to local file (sync)
                LocalStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferByteCount);
            }
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `await <stream>.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` you should write the number of bytes actually read by the previous read method (that value will be returned).

Comment: i tried that : int BytesRead = await .WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); then await DbStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, BytesRead ); still the same problem